# AudioFileOpenURL causes error -43 can't open file on simulator, but not device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-audio

I'm using AudioFileOpenURL to access an audio file. It works fine on my device, but not in the simulator. Here is where the error is being thrown:

```
        XThrowIfError(AudioFileOpenURL (sndFile, kAudioFileReadPermission, 0/*inFileTypeHint*/, &mAudioFile), "can't open file");
```

Any possible ideas why this might be?

---

**EDIT 1**

Here are my printouts of sndFile on the simulator and then on the device:

```
 SIMULATOR
 2011-04-13 12:20:10.259 iMC[51887:207] CreateQueueForFile       /var/folders/u6/u6pKbm2MFriwajkdt-OQME+++TI/-Tmp-/LoopExtended.wav
 2011-04-13 12:20:10.322 iMC[51887:207] sndFile  file://localhost/var/folders/u6/u6pKbm2MFriwajkdt-OQME+++TI/-Tmp-/LoopExtended.wav
 Error: can't open file (-43)
2011-04-13 12:20:10.323 iMC[51887:207] URL:                      /var/folders/u6/u6pKbm2MFriwajkdt-OQME+++TI/-Tmp-/LoopExtended.wav 




DEVICE 
2011-04-13 12:21:07.829 iMC[3061:307] CreateQueueForFile        /private/var/mobile/Applications/16194CBB-F0B3-4D39-9655-8FD67C247D74/tmp/LoopExtended.wav
2011-04-13 12:21:07.846 iMC[3061:307] sndFile   file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/16194CBB-F0B3-4D39-9655-8FD67C247D74/tmp/LoopExtended.wav
2011-04-13 12:21:07.859 iMC[3061:307] URL:                      /private/var/mobile/Applications/16194CBB-F0B3-4D39-9655-8FD67C247D74/tmp/LoopExtended.wav
```

---

**EDIT 2**

```
void AQPlayer::CreateQueueForFile(CFStringRef inFilePath) 
{   

// printf("CreateQueueForFile called \n ");

NSString *local_recordFilePath_NSString = (NSString *)inFilePath;
NSLog(@"CreateQueueForFile %@", local_recordFilePath_NSString );



CFURLRef sndFile = NULL; 

try {                   
    if (mFilePath == NULL)
    {
        mIsLooping = false;

        sndFile = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, inFilePath, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);
        if (!sndFile) { printf("can't parse file path\n"); return; }

        NSLog(@"sndFile   %@", sndFile);


        XThrowIfError(AudioFileOpenURL (sndFile, kAudioFileReadPermission, 0/*inFileTypeHint*/, &mAudioFile), "can't open file");



        UInt32 size = sizeof(mDataFormat);

        // printf("SIZE    %i\n ", size);
        XThrowIfError(AudioFileGetProperty(mAudioFile, 
                                       kAudioFilePropertyDataFormat, &size, &mDataFormat), "couldn't get file's data format");
        mFilePath = CFStringCreateCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, inFilePath);
    }
    SetupNewQueue();        
}
catch (CAXException e) {
    char buf[256];
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s (%s)\n", e.mOperation, e.FormatError(buf));
}
if (sndFile)
    CFRelease(sndFile);
 }
```

---

**EDIT 3**

```
CFStringRef local_recordFilePath;   

local_recordFilePath = (CFStringRef)[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"LoopExtended.wav"];



player->CreateQueueForFile(local_recordFilePath);
```

Comment: I think file URL is incorrect. please log your sndFile for both the cases. because device url scheme and simulator schemes are different.

Comment: hmmm... you may have something here. Could you expand on that?

Comment: What does sndFile prints for both cases? may be possible you are using some simulator specific path for url that device is unable to locate.

Comment: Okay. Gimme a second and I will print that out. Thanks

Comment: Allright, please see Edit 1. Thanks :)

Comment: this could be the problem. Ok please tell me how you are creating sndFile?

Comment: Please see EDIT 2. And thanks for all the effort ;)

Comment: paste this link in your browser file://localhost/var/folders/u6/u6pKbm2MFriwajkdt-OQME+++TI/-Tmp-/ do you see some files?

Comment: do you see LoopExtended.wav  file?

Comment: but I don't see LoopExtended.wav. Is this my problem?

Comment: I think problem is the file is outside the simulator's sandbox and it is in system folder. Have you put it  in resource bundle?

Comment: where is LoopExtended.wav file? in resource folder?

Comment: probably not. It has always been in the resources folder, but I don't know if it is in the bundle. How do I do that?

Comment: First reveal your .app(under Product) directory of your project and see package content. if you find LoopExtended.wav  file there than we have file but we still need to locate it. by the way what thing you supply in void AQPlayer::CreateQueueForFile(CFStringRef inFilePath) as iFilepath argument?

Comment: LoopExtended.wav is in the package contents. What should I do now? To answer your question see EDIT 3 (which I'm about to post. gimme a minute :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead.   (**UPDATED**)

```
 CFStringRef local_recordFilePath;   

    local_recordFilePath = (CFStringRef)[[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"LoopExtended.wav"];



    player->CreateQueueForFile(local_recordFilePath);
```

Problem was NSTemporaryDirectory() it returns operation system path it could be used for MacOS application not for iOS.

Thanks,

Comment: I tried this, but it crashed: warning: 'NSBundle' may not respond to '-stringByAppendingPathComponent:'. Could it be this?

Comment: [[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"LoopExtended.wav"]; use this I have updated it in above code.

Comment: Okay, we have gotten rid of the error, but now the whole app crashes shortly afterwards. I'm going to look into it further to see why that is. Thanks for all the help!